# facebook connect from android and from a web server

Tags: android, facebook

Is it possible to add facebook connect to my android application so the user authorize my

application and then access and retrieve user's info, friends list etc. from my web server?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the [Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/)?

Comment: of course I had.
I know it may be a noob question, but I wanted to make sure.

so if the user authorize my app through the android app, i can store his user id, and make all the requests from my server?

Comment: Using the Facebook API, you can retrieve and store the user's Facebook ID, but not his or her password. Then on your server, you can use another version of the Facebook API (not Android) and the user ID to perform tasks that do not require login.

Comment: lets say I want to retrieve real time updates on a user, I need offline permission for that?

Comment: You can receive updates using the Facebook API. I'm not really sure what you are asking. Is this a new question?